# Entity with two IDs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's assume I have defined the following Entity:

```
@Entity   
class User{  

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "DB_ID")
   private long id;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "LOGIN", unique = true)
   private String code;  

//setters, getters  
}
```

**Question #1.**
When I am using the method `.find(User.class, someId)`, what ID do I have to set? Should I use
the long field id or the String field code? Or I can I use the long field id, and String field code at the same time?

**Question #2.**
If I want to use the method `.merge(user)`, in which case will the record be updated?
case #1: - id equals DB_ID, code not equals LOGIN
case #2: - id not equals DB_ID, code equals LOGIN
case #3: - idequals DB_ID and code equals LOGIN
or any other condition?

Comment: Are those ids independent? If so, there's no way to do that, an entity must have exactly one id (which might consist of multiple fields though). In your case the `DB_ID` might be the actual id and the `LOGIN` column might just have the unique constraint and would have to be used in a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any class that has *composite* id (multiple Id fields) has to have its own IdClass defined (which you haven't done). An instance of the IdClass is what you then pass in to EM.find. This is easily enough found in the JPA spec

Answer (score -1):

For question 1 you should only pass the long ID because it is the primary key for your table and you need to find on basis of it.

Comment: The primary key is composite.